# How to set a DefaultSharedPreferences value?

Tags: android, default, shared, preference

I have a preferences activity with a checkbox "Enable Service".

I read the value like this :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
ServiceEnabled_Pref = prefs.getBoolean("EnableService", true);
```

ok, but how can I set this Preference ?

this is not a CustomShared Preference, It is a DefaultShared Preferences and it seems that there is not a method putBoolean for DefaultSharedPreferences.

I need this, cause I have a Widget with a button that needs to set this value to true/false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

programatically:

```
prefs.editor().putBoolean("EnableService", true).commit();
```

however your best bet for defining the preferenceActivity and its defaults is via an xml file as decribed [here](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) with the `android:defaultValue` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use the shared preferences editor:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html